# Spark SQL function for datetime is working for time format in AM not in PM

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am converting DateTime in AM/PM to 24 hours. The conversion for AM works fine but fails for PM and returns **null**. Please find below the sample

```
val seq = Seq((1,"abc","123","15/3/2021 02:00:00 AM"),(2,"pqr","456","15/3/2021 04:00:00 PM"),(1,"xyz","789","15/3/2021 09:00:00 AM"))

val df = seq.toDF("id","name","addr","time")

val time = df.withColumn("time2",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp($"time","dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"),"d MMMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"))

+---+----+----+---------------------+----------------------+
|id |name|addr|time                 |time2                 |
+---+----+----+---------------------+----------------------+
|1  |abc |123 |15/3/2021 02:00:00 AM|15 March 2021 02:00:00|
|2  |pqr |456 |15/3/2021 04:00:00 PM|null                  |
|1  |xyz |789 |15/3/2021 09:00:00 AM|15 March 2021 09:00:00|
+---+----+----+---------------------+----------------------+
```

Can someone suggest here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lower case `h` for `clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-12)` (see the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html)). Also, use 1 `M` because the given format has only 1 number for month; for long form of month in result, use 4 `M` instead of 5.

```
val time = df.withColumn(
    "time2",
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp($"time","dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"),"d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss")
)

time.show(false)
+---+----+----+---------------------+----------------------+
|id |name|addr|time                 |time2                 |
+---+----+----+---------------------+----------------------+
|1  |abc |123 |15/3/2021 02:00:00 AM|15 March 2021 02:00:00|
|2  |pqr |456 |15/3/2021 04:00:00 PM|15 March 2021 16:00:00|
|1  |xyz |789 |15/3/2021 09:00:00 AM|15 March 2021 09:00:00|
+---+----+----+---------------------+----------------------+
```